# Loading records on demand in Kendo TreeView in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I want to load records in Kendo TreeView on demand , when user reaches to the end of records list(for example - 20 records) and after that load next 20 records.
This i want to implement in MVC, can anybody assist me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement this feature in MVC. Kendo compontents in MVC Views are only HTML Helpers that are replaced by html + javascript by Kendo dll.

You can only implement it in JavaScript. You should catch scroll event. Check if it reach desired position to get more elements. Then you need to get this elements from service, add them to your tree dataSource and refresh/recreate your treeView.